# jquery show/hide code with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a bit of a backwards question but here goes...
After searching the web and stackoverflow, I found a piece of code (below) that "almost" works for what I want it to do. It shows the fields on pageload until it is checked and I want it to hide the fields until it is checked.  I don't understand jQuery very well and even after going through a few tutorials, I don't know what to change to make it work for what I want!  Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        $("." + inputValue).toggle();
    });
});

  <div class="form-group form-group-sm">   
                <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="shipDiff" value="1" onkeyup="getResults()"> Shipping address different than billing address?</label>                
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="1">
< div ...rest of fields here...>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class can not start with a number

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");//true > show; false > hide
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    $("." + inputValue).toggle(checked);
  });
});
```

```css
.one{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">   
                <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="shipDiff" value="one" onkeyup="getResults()"> Shipping address different than billing address?</label>                
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="one"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks avril - that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

jquery :

```
function getResults(){
   if ($('#shipDiff').is(':checked')){
       $('.testClass').hide();
    }
else{
      $('.testClass').show();
    }
}
```

HTML :

```
 <div class="form-group form-group-sm">   
            <div class="input-group col-md-12">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="shipDiff" value="1" id="shipDiff" onclick="getResults()"> Shipping address different than billing address?</label>                
            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="testClass">
    <strong>This Is My Contents</strong>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/hbny0mrL/